# Redirecting to wrong URL in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Created AccountController with Register action Method

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

and on Logon View I have created link for Register

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register","Account")
```

But when I click on Register Link it redirect wrong like this

`localhost:8090/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fRegister`

instead of

`//localhost:8090/Account/Register`

will appreciate your help

Comment: how have you mapped your routes?

Comment: Try `@Html.ActionLink("Register","Account")`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly write `[AllowAnonymous]` over register action method.